# Why study the eigenvalues of Sturm-Liouville problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We know that the Sturm-Lioville's problem is:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
-\frac{d}{dt}(pu)+qu=f\\
\alpha_1u(a)+\beta_1u'(a)=0\\
\alpha_2u(b)+\beta_2u'(b)=0
\end{array}\right.$$
and the solution is:
$$u(t)=\mathcal{G}(f)(t)$$
with:
$$\mathcal{G}(f)(t)=\int_a^b G(t,s)f(s) ds$$

Why is important the study of the eigenvalues of the problem:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
-\frac{d}{dt}(pu)+qu=\lambda r u\\
\alpha_1u(a)+\beta_1u'(a)=0\\
\alpha_2u(b)+\beta_2u'(b)=0
\end{array}\right.$$
for some function $r$ ?

Many thanks !!